# How to eager load associated table with conditions and current user?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, orm, rails-activerecord

Im trying to reduce the number of queries from n+1 to a couple for hacks that have favorites.

User has many hacks. (the creator of the hack)
Hack has many favorites
User has many favorites 
Favorites belongs to hack and user.

Favorites is just a join table. It only contains foreign keys, nothing else.

On the hacks index page, I display a star icon based on whether a favorite record exists for the given hack and current_user.

index.hmtl

```
- @hacks.each do |h| 
  - if h.favorites(current_user)
    #star image
```

How do I use active record or raw SQL in a '.SQL' method call to eager load the relevant favorites?

I'm thinking first get the paginated hacks, get the current user, and query all of the favorites that have the hack and the current user.

I'm not sure on the syntax. Also Current_user cannot be called from models.

---

**Update:**

I tried these queries

```
@hacks = Hack.includes(:tags, :users, :favorites).where("favorites.user_id = ?", current_user.id).references(:favorites)
```

I've also tried the following, and both of them without the `.references` method

```
@hacks = Hack.includes(:tags, :users, :favorites).where(favorites: { user_id: current_user.id } ).references(:favorites)
```

The WHERE clause acts on hacks to limit the type of hacks. 
But what I want is to limit the favorites to the ones with the condition instead (i.e. favorites.user_id = current_user.id).

(After all, many thousands of user may favorite a hack, but the client side is only concerned with the current user, so loading all the users that favorited the hack could be very expensive and bad)

How can I make conditions apply to eager loaded associations rather than the original model?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :hack`, would it be safe to assume that you have a "has many through" relationship setup between `favorites`, `hack` and `user`?  Following is how you could eager load Hack with Favorites and Users.

```
# app/controllers/hacks_controller.b

def index
  @hacks = Hack.includes(favorites: :user)
end
```

The above code is going to run three queries, one to select all from `hacks`, second join between `hacks` with `favorites`, and third select all from `users` with `users` already selected in the second query through `favorites`.

Another way to execute these joins in a single query would be to use an inner join using `joins`:

```
# app/controllers/hacks_controller.b

def index
  @hacks = Hack.joins(favorites: :user)
end
```

With this query, there is only one query with inner join between the three tables, `users`, `favorites` and `hacks`.

Comment: Yes, It would be user. through favorites. But I also have `user has many hacks` for the creator of the hack. Can you have has many, and has many through for the same two models?

Does your answer assume that, or does it change things?

Comment: I was trying to use `.eager_load` to do a single query.

Comment: I have other conditions as well, like `tagged_with(params[:tag])` (this is a custom scope method provided by acts_as_taggable_on gem)

I am also using pagination, namely kaminari (doesn't really matter), which appends `.page(params[:page]).per(20)`

I thought it would be more efficient to run the conditions and the pagination, then query the associated favorites and users on just those hacks. Or does it do a single query for each paginated page request, and doesn't matter?

Sorry to throw a bunch of questions. Please feel free to answer as many or few as you wish. no worries =]

Comment: @gwho, my apologies to say that I am not familiar with kaminari yet, I would suggest  you to try the second query out.  Have you tried them in the rails console yet?  That would explain much better.

Comment: I just meant other conditions that return a subset in general, and whether or made a difference when you call includes.

Comment: The queries work fine without pagination in the console. Thank you. Let's leave kaminari out of the picture for now. I am still getting N+1 queries for favorites. I'll update the OP with my query

Comment: @gwho, can you try: `Hack.includes(:tags, [ favorites: :user ])`?

Comment: For now, I'm not doing a has many through. I just have the user who created the hack. I've what you're doing, and it would certainly preload what I need. But it would preload too many favorites, and too many users. I need a subset of favorites, which is based on just the current user.  I need a subset of the favorites inner joined one way or another with the current user.

Comment: Apparently there is one workaround to doing queries based on dynamic variables evaluated at runtime (like Time.now or current_user). http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/ which links to this one that shows how to do it. http://mrbrdo.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/manually-preloading-associations-in-rails-using-custom-scopessql/ I'm stuck on the second one though.